# [1]: ORA-00904: "VW_D"."CL_NAME": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run this code in Oracle database but it's giving error :

> ```
>  ORA-00904: "vw_d"."cl_name": invalid identifier
> ```

What's wrong with the query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM vw_doctrans vw_d
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM vw_doctrans vw
                 WHERE vw.cl_name = vw_d.cl_name
                 GROUP BY vw.country)) > 1
```

I tried this query in MySQL and works fine

Comment: show the query you tried in mysql; what you show gives `Unknown column 'vw_d.CL_NAME' in 'where clause'` even when the missing subquery alias is added

Comment: but this seems a lot easier to do with a simple join than your attempt at a correlated subquery

Comment: could your share please how to do it?

Comment: This query is horrible and I can't imagine there is no better way. Avoid to use *, that's not recommended at all. Also doing as many subqueries as possible is not recommended. You would do better to simplify the query. Please show sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: I can share what I guess at what you are trying, but I'd like you to show the query that "works fine" in mysql, as well as explain in English what you are trying to do, to validate my guesses

Comment: Application: receiving messages from countries. Database: Table included cl_name, date, text, country. One 'cl_name' has 2 and more  same and diffrent 'country'. Outcome: show 'cl_name' which mesages came from 2 and more different(not same) countries AND if message came from same country 2-3times show only one time the country. Example: Messages for Bob came from UK,USA and UAE several times, message for John came from Canada 2 times, message for Caroline came from India, several times from USA. Outcome:  Bob with countries, Caroline 1 row India and one row USA (not several times USA).

Comment: I guess explained well)

Comment: so you don't want the just the distinct country and cl_name for any cl_name that has more than one country, not any other columns?

Comment: ah sorry did't tell, I need also other columns too: Bob with countries, date, message of text. Not only cl_name and country column

Comment: *`.. select * .. group by vw.COUNTRY ..`* The query is incorrect. *I tried this query in MySQL and works fine* Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - and MySQL will fail. OracleDB have no such setting and will fail always. Make your query correct.

Comment: Please reome your comments. Comment's purpose is not writing down requirements. Edit your question and show sample input and expected result as tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like

Sample data:

```
SQL> with vw_doctrans (id, cl_name, country) as
  2    (select 1, 'Bob', 'UK' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Bob', 'USA' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Bob', 'UAE' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Bob', 'UAE' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Bob', 'UAE' from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 6, 'John', 'Canada' from dual union all
  9     select 7, 'John', 'Canada' from dual union all
 10     --
 11     select 8, 'Caroline', 'India' from dual union all
 12     select 9, 'Caroline', 'USA' from dual union all
 13     select 10, 'Caroline', 'USA' from dual union all
 14     select 11, 'Caroline', 'USA' from dual
 15    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 16  temp as
 17    (select v.*,
 18            count(distinct country) over (partition by cl_name) cnt
 19     from vw_doctrans v
 20    )
 21  select distinct cl_name, country
 22  from temp
 23  where cnt >= 2
 24  order by cl_name, country;

CL_NAME  COUNTR
-------- ------
Bob      UAE
Bob      UK
Bob      USA
Caroline India
Caroline USA

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: if the table already existed (i.e. without a CTE)]**

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * from vw_doctrans;

        ID CL_NAME  COUNTR
---------- -------- ------
         1 Bob      UK
         2 Bob      USA
         3 Bob      UAE
         4 Bob      UAE
         5 Bob      UAE
         6 John     Canada
         7 John     Canada
         8 Caroline India
         9 Caroline USA
        10 Caroline USA
        11 Caroline USA

11 rows selected.
```

Here's how to use a CTE (that's line #16 in previous query):

```
SQL> with temp as
  2       (select v.*,
  3               count(distinct country) over (partition by cl_name) cnt
  4        from vw_doctrans v
  5       )
  6     select distinct cl_name, country
  7     from temp
  8     where cnt >= 2
  9     order by cl_name, country;

CL_NAME  COUNTR
-------- ------
Bob      UAE
Bob      UK
Bob      USA
Caroline India
Caroline USA

SQL>
```

Comment: I have already Views in Oracle which can call also different informations from different tables. Based on that how can I use this query to that Views? Is there any other options of query? Thank you!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you'd **join** these views to table(s) involved here, i.e. VW_DOCTRANS.

Comment: join these views to table? like how?

Comment: Like any other join. `select ... from vw_doctrans d join other_table t on d.id = t.id ...`

Comment: Not possible, sorry.

Comment: what means here 'temp as'? I tried this but gives error in 'from temp' line: table or view doesn't exist

Comment: It is name of the CTE (a Common Table Expression, also know as the WITH factoring clause). Just put that keyword - WITH - in front of the TEMP: `with temp as ...`

Comment: I put and know says "missing SELECT keyword")))) are there could be 2 and more WITH clause in a query?

Comment: You did something wrong, then. I edited the answer and posted how to do it properly.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: and how about to display other columns also with this query you posted?

Comment: Specify all columns you want in SELECT column list.

Comment: like: `select clm1, clm2, clm3... , distinct cl_name, country ....`   ?

Comment: DISTINCT has to follow SELECT immediately; you can't put it in the middle of the column list. So: `select distinct clm1, clm2, ... cl_name, country, ...`

Comment: We can't make it easy to make `table.*` or something else? to make good code and not enter if there more than 20 columns

Comment: Best practices suggest that you should avoid `select *`, but it's up to you.

Comment: So, only one way is to write all available columns with distinct clause?

Comment: thank you so much, I aapriciate. it's working now but executing very very slow although there are not much data. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You are way overthinking it.  This is just:

```
SELECT vw_d.cl_name, vw_d.country
FROM vw_doctrans vw_d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM vw_doctrans vw
    WHERE vw.cl_name = vw_d.cl_name AND vw.country != vw_d.country
)
GROUP BY vw_d.cl_name, vw_d.country
```

But your "I need also other columns too: Bob with countries, date, message of text. Not only cl_name and country column" directly conflicts with your "if message came from same country 2-3times show only one time the country."  You can't have both; if you want only one row for each name/country combination, you need to decide how to pick which values for the other columns you want.

Comment: and how to check by quantity of country. Example I want to check cl_name which message came from 2, 3 and more different countries.

Comment: I am checking that there is record for the same cl_name in a different country, in the where condition in the exists subquery.

Comment: this I understood and it worked in Oracle thank you so much, but  also if I want to check quantity different countries from same cl_name  how to do that?

Comment: Example I need to show record for cl_name which messages came from 4 and more different countries

Comment: then you want to do a self-join and COUNTDISTINCT (which will not be compatible with mysql).  you should ask a new question for that.